# A click counter for multiple email addresses and mailto

Tags: javascript, php

I have several e-mail addresses on one page that should be numbered or incremented when they are sent. For this I have a counter.php that contains the count and evaluation.php that brings together the email addresses and the count. When you call evaluation.php, a counter.txt is created that contains the current calls. Then a counter.log is created that documents the calls. If a link is then clicked in the evaluation.php, a subject with the most recent number of views is transmitted. With link 1, both the subject is transmitted and the counter.log is filled. With link 2 and link 3, the counter.log is transmitted but the subject remains empty. Unfortunately I don't know why.

### counter.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['ip-sperre'])||$_SESSION['ip-sperre'] < time()- 30){
    $_SESSION['ip-sperre'] = time();

    @$incoming = $_GET['sendValue'];
    $filename = $incoming."_counter.txt";

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $file = fopen($filename,"r+");
        $zaehler = fgets($file,255);
        fclose($file);  
    } else {
        $zaehler = 0;   
    }
    

    $zaehler++;
    
    echo 'E-Mail ' . $zaehler;

    $file = fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($file,$zaehler);
    fclose($file);

    $inhalt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' - '.$incoming.': '.$zaehler."\n";
    $file2 = fopen("counter.log","a+");
    fwrite($file2,$inhalt);
    fclose($file2);

} else {
    // echo "Sperre aktiv";
}
?>
```

### evaluation.php

```
<?php
    include 'counter.php';
?>

<!--E-Mail 1-->
<a href="mailto:email1?subject=<?php echo $subject=$zaehler; ?>">Email recipient</a> <br>

<!--E-Mail 2-->
<a href="mailto:email2?subject=<?php echo $subject=$zaehler; ?>">Email recipient</a> <br>

<!--E-Mail 2-->
<a href="mailto:email3?subject=<?php echo $subject=$zaehler; ?>">Email recipient</a> <br>

<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!--Counter-->
<script>
function count(e) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "counter.php?sendValue=" + e, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}   

/*Reload*/  
$('a').click(function() {
    location.reload();
}); 
</script>
```

### result click link 1 with filled subject

[image]

### result click link 2 with empty subject

[image]

Comment: First thought, you've got three click handlers on your links, possibly a race condition? One is the `href`, one is the `onclick`, and one is the jQuery stuff. Second, the `else` in your counter emits nothing which appears to map to your "blank" scenario, so I'm guess your `if` condition isn't triggering.

Comment: Thank you for the message. I would like to solve these. But don't know how. I need Href because it connects the e-mail message. I need jQuery so that the page reloads as soon as the link is clicked and continues to count up. The onlick should serve to differentiate the "recipient" mails and is important. They were right about the if condition. As soon as I take the code out of the condition, incrementing works for all links. Do you maybe have a suggestion what I can do better? For example, how do I prevent the race condition or how does the if condition no longer give an empty output. Thanks